# Looping through array in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to use arrays in mysql stored procedures.

i.e. array would look like

```
(0 =>array('name','value','value1'), 1=> array('name1','value2','value3))
```

I want to loop through each of them and perform some action on different tables. Can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) do not accept arrays; you can, however, send as many input values as you want, as long as it matches the number and types of parameters declared in the stored procedure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to pass more then one item, then use additional (temporary) table instead of IN parameters.
- If you need to pass items one by one - `('name','value','value1')`, then use some IN parameters - `(IN name VARCHAR(255), IN value1 INT(11), IN value2 INT(11))`